# How to convert 32-bit visual basic 2010 web service setup to 64-bit

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have visual studio 2010 web service application whose setup file install the service in 32-Bit.

I want to convert this service setup to target it 64-Bit.

Is there way to to convert service from 32-bit to 64-bit.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2010 64 bit, then you can remake it for 64-bit

Comment: @Karuntos Visual Studio is a 32-bit program. However, it can still create 64-bit programs.